# Can't Jump on Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem about jump for a character..
I can use CharacterMotor.Move() for jumping, but no .SimpleMove(), why?

This is my class at the moment:

```
public float speed = 10.0f;
public float rotationSpeed = 10.0f;
public float jumpSpeed = 50.0f;
public float gravitySpeed = 30.0f;

public string Avancer = "z";
public string Reculer = "s";
public string RotationGauche = "q";
public string RotationDroite = "d";
public string SlideGauche = "a";
public string SlideDroite = "e";
public string Jump = "space";

CharacterController cc;
Vector3 newPos;

public void Start()
{
    cc = GetComponent<CharacterController> ();
}

public void Update()
{
            /*Movements part*/
            if (Input.GetKey (Avancer.ToString ())) {
                    newPos = new Vector3 (speed, 0, 0);
                    newPos = transform.rotation * newPos;
                    cc.SimpleMove (newPos);
            } else if (Input.GetKey (Reculer.ToString ())) {
                    newPos = new Vector3 (speed * -1, 0, 0);
                    newPos = transform.rotation * newPos;
                    cc.SimpleMove (newPos);
            } else if (Input.GetKey (SlideGauche.ToString ())) {
                    newPos = new Vector3 (0, 0, speed);
                    newPos = transform.rotation * newPos;
                    cc.SimpleMove (newPos);
            } else if (Input.GetKey (SlideDroite.ToString ())) {
                    newPos = new Vector3 (0, 0, speed * -1);
                    newPos = transform.rotation * newPos;
                    cc.SimpleMove (newPos);
            } else if (Input.GetKey (RotationGauche.ToString ())) {
                    transform.Rotate (0, rotationSpeed * -1, 0);
            } else if (Input.GetKey (RotationDroite.ToString ())) {
                    transform.Rotate (0, rotationSpeed, 0);
            } else if (cc.isGrounded && Input.GetKeyDown (Jump.ToString ())) {
                    newPos = new Vector3 (0, jumpSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
                    cc.SimpleMove (newPos);
                    //cc.Move (newPos);
                    print ("JUMP !");
            } else if (!cc.isGrounded) {
                    newPos = new Vector3 (0, (gravitySpeed * Time.deltaTime) * -1, 0);
                    cc.SimpleMove (newPos);
                    print ("en l'air");
            }
            /*Movements part*/


    }
```

I just not understand why it don't perform

So if you can help me, thank you

***EDIT***

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Mouse Look")]
public class palskie : MonoBehaviour
{   
public float speed = 1000000.0f;
public float rotationSpeed = 10.0f;
public float jumpSpeed = 100.0f;
public float gravitySpeed = 50f;

public string Avancer = "z";
public string Reculer = "s";
public string RotationGauche = "q";
public string RotationDroite = "d";
public string SlideGauche = "a";
public string SlideDroite = "e";
public string Jump = "space";

private CharacterController cc;
Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;

public int ammo = 100;
public int life = 100;

public void Start()
{
    cc = GetComponent<CharacterController> ();
}

public void Update()
{
            /*Movements part*/
            Vector3 direction;// = Vector3.zero;

            if (cc.isGrounded && Input.GetKeyDown (Jump.ToString ())) {
                    dir.y = jumpSpeed;
                    direction = dir;
            } else if (!cc.isGrounded) {
                    dir.y -= gravitySpeed;
                    direction = dir;
            } else {
                    direction = Vector3.zero;
            }

            if (Input.GetKey (Avancer.ToString ())) {
                    direction.x = speed;


            } else if (Input.GetKey (Reculer.ToString ())) {
                    direction.x -= speed;
            }
            if (Input.GetKey (SlideGauche.ToString ())) {

                    direction.z = speed;
            } else if (Input.GetKey (SlideDroite.ToString ())) {
                    direction.z = -speed;
            }
            if (Input.GetKey (RotationGauche.ToString ())) {
                    transform.Rotate (0, rotationSpeed * -1, 0);
            } else if (Input.GetKey (RotationDroite.ToString ())) {
                    transform.Rotate (0, rotationSpeed, 0);
            }

            //Transformer le Vector3 en direction local
            direction = transform.TransformDirection (direction);

            //Deplacement du personnage
            cc.Move (direction * Time.deltaTime);

            transform.Rotate (0, Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * rotationSpeed, 0);
            /*Movements part*/
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider obj)
    {
            if ((obj.gameObject.name == "Healt")) {
                    life += 5;
                    if (life > 100) 
                            life = 100;
                    Destroy (obj.gameObject);
            } else if ((obj.gameObject.name == "Ammo")) {
                    ammo += 5;
                    if (ammo > 200)
                            ammo = 200;
                    Destroy (obj.gameObject);
            }

    }

}
```

last edit, it works ! :) We found solution  after long search ;)
Thank for you help :)

[SOLVED]

Answer (score 4):

According to [Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.SimpleMove.html), you can't and should not try to jump with the SimpleMove function. It clearly states on the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.SimpleMove.html) page of [**SimpleMove**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.SimpleMove.html) that **SimpleMove** will ignore any attempt to add force to the **y-axis** which is what you are doing. It is designed like that for thier own reason. Use the **Move** function as they made it for jumping.

Also the last line of your if statement code  `!cc.isGrounded` is not required if you are using the **SimpleMove** function. The document again states that gravity is automatically applied to it when the object is moving.

For some reason I was able to get **SimpleMove** to work but the gravity pulling it down is too weak. If you want to try this, replace

`newPos = new Vector3 (0, jumpSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);`

with

```
newPos = new Vector3 (0, 1 * jumpSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
```

then change the `public float jumpSpeed = 50.0f;`

to

```
public float jumpSpeed = 60000f;
```

It works but doesn't look good at all. You should go with the Move function instead.

**EDIT:**

***"you say SimpleMove() can't do anything on Y-axis, then why my Y-axis is edit when I fall, I mean of gravaity?"*** It looks like you are doubting me. That's fine. It is your responsibility to click and read the the link I posted.

***"The problem is, if I don't add gravity code, my character stay in fly, the other problem is, when I jump with Move(), It's like a teleportation"*** That's what you have said your problem was in the beginiing. It can be solve easily with the Move function by using **Time.deltaTime** to smooth out the y-axis movement.

Forget about the code I posted above. It worked but then stopped working after I restarted Unity. I guess it was a bug that made it to work in the first place.

I have changed your code to have smooth jumping with the Move function. I only changed the **jumping** and the **gravity** part of the code. Just copy the whole code and replace it with what you posted above. You shouldn't have any problem then. Make sure to **reset** the **Character Controller** values to **default** in Editor then **reset** the values of this **script** in the Editor too so that it will use the **default** values from the script. You can adjust the **gravitySpeed** and **jumpSpeed** to suit your needs after you test it.

```
    public float speed = 10.0f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 10.0f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 130;
    public float gravitySpeed = 80.0f;

    public string Avancer = "z";
    public string Reculer = "s";
    public string RotationGauche = "q";
    public string RotationDroite = "d";
    public string SlideGauche = "a";
    public string SlideDroite = "e";
    public string Jump = "space";

    CharacterController cc;
    Vector3 newPos;

    public void Start ()
    {
        cc = GetComponent<CharacterController> ();
    }

    public void Update ()
    {
        /*Movements part*/
        if (Input.GetKey (Avancer.ToString ())) {
            newPos = new Vector3 (speed, 0, 0);
            newPos = transform.rotation * newPos;
            cc.SimpleMove (newPos);
        } else if (Input.GetKey (Reculer.ToString ())) {
            newPos = new Vector3 (speed * -1, 0, 0);
            newPos = transform.rotation * newPos;
            cc.SimpleMove (newPos);
        } else if (Input.GetKey (SlideGauche.ToString ())) {
            newPos = new Vector3 (0, 0, speed);
            newPos = transform.rotation * newPos;
            cc.SimpleMove (newPos);
        } else if (Input.GetKey (SlideDroite.ToString ())) {
            newPos = new Vector3 (0, 0, speed * -1);
            newPos = transform.rotation * newPos;
            cc.SimpleMove (newPos);
        } else if (Input.GetKey (RotationGauche.ToString ())) {
            transform.Rotate (0, rotationSpeed * -1, 0);
        } else if (Input.GetKey (RotationDroite.ToString ())) {
            transform.Rotate (0, rotationSpeed, 0);
        } else if (cc.isGrounded && Input.GetKeyDown (Jump.ToString ())) {
            newPos = new Vector3 (0, jumpSpeed, 0);
            cc.Move (newPos * Time.deltaTime);
            print ("JUMP !");
        } 

        if (!cc.isGrounded) {
            newPos.y -= gravitySpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            cc.Move (newPos * Time.deltaTime);
            print ("en l'air");
        }
        /*Movements part*/


    }
```

Comment: Hi,

The problem is,  if I don't add gravity code, my character stay in fly, the other problem is, when I jump with Move(), It's like a teleportation... you say SimpleMove() can't do anything on Y-axis, then why my Y-axis is edit when I fall, I mean of gravaity?
At the moment, I can just jump like téléportation, and all time at the same level, I mean, I can't jump more highter..
I Tested your code and it doesn't change anything

Comment: It's always the same :/ .... My character can teleport himseft, but not jump like real

Comment: The code i posted above should work and is still working on my side. That's the recommend way of jumping. What Unity version are you using? Did you reset the values like I mentioned? If you have rigidbody attached the game object the script is attached to, remove it.  If you want to upload your scene or create simple scene that doesn't work that's fine. I will be able to look at it. This should work. Mine worked with a simple cube and it jumps and lands smoothly. You are doing something wrong and the only way to find out what that is, is to look at your scene.